# WordPress password as plain text in email

Tags: users, user-registration, user-access

I am working on a project and we need to send users current passwords when they log in.

So the only option is to the use the password reset feature when the user enters the email, an email will be sent to the user with a username and password so that they can log in.

Is there any way? to send user current password on email as plain text?

please need exact solution

Comment: Please can you explain why you need to do this. It sounds like a bad idea to me.

Comment: This would be a ***major*** security risk and a breach of many regulations and legal requirements in many countries and jurisdictions. WP currently sends users a link to set their initial/first password, but does not send the actual password. You should never send any passwords via email even temporary ones

Answer (score 3):

No, WordPress passwords are not stored in plain text. They're stored as hashes generated by an old version of PHPass, which I think does multiple rounds of salted MD5 hashes. You cannot extract the original password from this, by design.

See [Why shouldn't I store passwords in plain text?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/120540/9079) on Information Security StackExchange.

If you really really must do this, and I really can't see why you should, the web request that performs the login will have the user's password available in clear that you can use there and then. But there is absolutely no reason to tell the user the secret string they've just entered in your login box because they already know it don't they?